# Invalid Identifier SQL ORA-00904

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I am trying to do a query that I have created to count a country ID, however I am getting the ORA-00904 error with my OEHR_LOCATIONS.REGION_ID on the Group BY line 4.

```
SELECT OEHR_COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID, REGION_ID, COUNT (OEHR_COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID)
FROM OEHR_COUNTRIES, OEHR_LOCATIONS
WHERE OEHR_COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID = OEHR_LOCATIONS.COUNTRY_ID
GROUP BY OEHR_COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID, OEHR_LOCATIONS.REGION_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for what might be causing your error, but I would encourage you to write the query more like this:

```
SELECT c.COUNTRY_ID, l.REGION_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM OEHR_COUNTRIES c JOIN
     OEHR_LOCATIONS l
     ON c.COUNTRY_ID = l.COUNTRY_ID
GROUP BY c.COUNTRY_ID, l.REGION_ID;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Table aliases make the table easier to write and to read.
- There is no need to count a column that is never `NULL`.  That is what `COUNT(*)` does.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the input I have redone my query however I am still getting the same invalid identifier error on my same line of code on the GROUP BY line.

Comment: Presumably, there is no column called `REGION_ID` in `OEHR_LOCATIONS`.

Comment: There is and I have made sure, I have double checked with the database I am querying and it is there I can only think its something with the query throwing up the error.

Comment: Never mind I found an issue on a syntax thanks for your input however!